# Alternating Least Squares for Matrix Factorization with biases

Tags: recommender-system

I am attempting to use ALS for matrix factorization, using a loss function that includes user and item biases $c_i$, $d_j$,

$$
L = \sum_{(i,j) \in S} (r_{ij} - x_i\cdot y_j^\top - c_i - d_j)^2 + \lambda(\Vert x_i \Vert^2 + \Vert y_j \Vert^2 + c_i^2 + d_j^2)
$$

where $r_{ij}$ is the rating given by user $i$ on item $j$, $x_i$ and $y_j$ are the latent factor vectors of user $i$ and item $j$, respectively, and $\lambda$ is the regularization parameter. How would you go about implementing ALS using this loss function? For a loss function without bias terms, the ALS updates of user and item matrices $U$, $V$ would be

$$
U = RV(V^\top V + \lambda I)^{-1} 
$$
$$
V = RU(U^\top U + \lambda I)^{-1}
$$

(where $R$ is the ratings matrix with unknown ratings set to zero) but with bias terms I'm not sure how to carry out the derivation.

Comment: It seems to me that if you replaced $x_i$ with the vector $(x_i;c_i,1)$ and $y_j$ with $(y_j;1,d_j),$  then you could express $L$ purely in terms of $R,$ the $x_i,$ the $y_j,$ and $\lambda,$ thereby eliminating the explicit appearance of any bias terms.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a good approach, but then minimizing with respect to the modified vectors/matrices needs to have the constraint that one element/column equals 1. Do I just perform the update in the same way as before, but then reset the columns that need to be equal to 1 after each update?